# How to view bluetooth adapters, and select which adapter a device connects to?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

In a system with multiple network cards, each of which support both wifi and bluetooth, the Settings app will display each of the wifi adapters in the "Wifi" tab, but not in the bluetooth tab. How to select which bluetooth adapter a device connects to?

[image: Wi-Fi tab]

[image: Bluetooth tab]